# How to call a Python function that controls a computer player in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a fairly functional clone of Tetris running on Pygame, where the player competes against a CPU player. The way the CPU player works consists of brute-forcing the best move it can, then calculating the moves needed to get there. This all is run through a singular function, `ai.run`, which will do one of the following:

1. Nothing because it's not time for the AI to move yet (there's a maximum reaction time to make it beatable),
2. Make the next move required to reach its intended position, or
3. Spend about 4/10 of a second calculating its next move.

This setup works quite well, and without the computer player it consistently hits about 55 FPS on my low-end and overworked machine. However, on the frames it needs to calculate the next move, it will drop to about 7 FPS, resulting in a painful stutter about every 3 seconds. Therefore, I feel the solution is to move the computer player to a separate thread.

I have looked into both threading and multiprocessing, but can't figure out how to get either to do what I need it to do. How might this be done?

EDIT: Code might be useful here; you can find this program at [this repository](https://github.com/zombiepigdragon/Tetris-VS-AI). It should be noted that there is no multiprocessing implemented in this yet, as I have yet to find anything resembling a solution.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've tried. Both threading and multiprocessing should work fine.   There's no way we can know what to tell you here because you've given us nothing to go on. - your main challenge is probably going to be communicating between the two threads.

Comment: run calculations in thread and use queue to send move to main thread. In mainloop you check events to get move from player, and you should check queue to get move from computer. in queue you have to use non-blocking method so it will not stop mainloop and it will run all time. Or maybe thread could use `pygame.event` to send move to mainloop.

Comment: @Steve I posted a link to the GitHub repository, if that helps. I believe multiprocessing should help, hence the tag, but I couldn't figure out how to use it. Every online guide seems to like its print function pool, but no one has covered what I'm looking for.

Comment: @furas I don't know how to do that, hence the question. All my research found me a way to print 1 through 10 in another thread, nothing that I need for this.